# how to use AsyncTask in android 4.2

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

i am using AsyncTask class in my first activity its work fine
and call second and i am call another AsyncTask call object in onCreate 
and call the webservice in doInBackground 
then its give exception 
android.os.networkmainthread.

i am not getting any idea as
i am new to android development
so please show me some sample or i show you my code

this is my code

```
public class panel extends Activity {


@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.panel);
   User_Balance_Load Balance_load=new User_Balance_Load();
   Balance_load.execute();
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),Cls_Constant.username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}
class User_Balance_Load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(panel.this);
    protected void onPreExecute() { 

        this.dialog.setMessage("Loding Diet type..."); 
        this.dialog.show(); 
                                    } 

    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        panel.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Update_balance();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
    { 

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) 
            { 
            this.dialog.dismiss(); 
            }


     } 

}
void Update_balance()
{

    Vector result;
    result=Cls_webservice.User_Balance(Cls_Constant.Guid);
    if(result.size()>0)
    {
        String UserBalance=result.elementAt(2).toString();
        TextView Tv_User_balacne=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_point_balance);
        Tv_User_balacne.setText(UserBalance);
    }
}
```

And this is my class of webservice

```
public class Cls_webservice {


 public static Vector User_Balance(String id)
    { 
        Vector _vector = new Vector();
        final String userid = id;

        final String METHOD_NAME = "WCFDatatableRes";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/WCFDatatableRes";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String URL = "http://xxxxxxxx.com/GameRoom/ANDROIDLOTT/WebService.asmx";
        String return_val="";
        SoapObject newob;
        try
        {
            Object response;
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE , METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("Params", userid+",3"); 
            Request.addProperty("Do", "Balance"); 
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
            AndroidHttpTransport httptransport ;
            httptransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

            httptransport.debug=true;
            try
            {

                httptransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                response = envelope.getResponse();
                newob = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                return_val = newob.toString();
                SoapObject diettype_listResult = (SoapObject) newob.getProperty("WCFDatatableRes ") ;
                SoapObject diffgram = (SoapObject) diettype_listResult.getProperty("diffgram") ;

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error:" + e);
            }                 

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return _vector;
    }
```

}

The exception come in this line -> "httptransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
so please help me 
and this same code work in 
my first activity
i don't know why in second come error
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an asynctask and then in your asynctask you're running code under the UI thread. That is nonsense, since the result is the same as executing the code on the OnCreate() method.

```
protected Void doInBackground(final Void... unused) 
{
    Vector result = Update_balance();
    panel.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(result.size()>0)
            {
                String UserBalance=result.elementAt(2).toString();
                TextView Tv_User_balacne=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_point_balance);
                Tv_User_balacne.setText(UserBalance);
            }                
        }
    });
    return null;
}

Vector Update_balance()
{
    Vector result;
    result=Cls_webservice.User_Balance(Cls_Constant.Guid);
    return result;
}
```